# Matplotlib pcolor with varying Y bins

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphics, plot

All,

I am trying to find a way to reproduce this plot in matplotlib. Let me explain what is going on and provide some sample data. This is created from a 1D X array containing times. There is a 2D Y array containing the time dependent bins in the Y direction. There is a 2D Z array containing the value that is then plotted in color. The challenge here is that [pcolor()](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=pcolor#matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolor) and [pcolormesh()](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh) both take 1D, 1D, 2D

[image: Plot to replicate]

Lets create some sample data:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.linspace(0, 100, 200)
Y = np.tile(np.logspace(0, 4, 15), len(X)).reshape(len(X), -1)
Y[::4, :] += 50
Z = np.logspace(0, 7, (np.product(Y.shape))).reshape(Y.shape)
print(X.shape, Y.shape, Z.shape)
# (200,) (200, 15) (200, 15)
```

It seems like [np.meshgrid()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) could play a role here but I am not having luck there and it gets really slow. Another option is to make all the corners of the boxes and like [pcolor()](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=pcolor#matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolor) use [matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection()](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection) but I seem to have a mental block against getting this right.

Anyone have other thoughts or code samples?

Comment: I'm a little confused as to exactly what you want but it sounds like `griddata` may help with what you need http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html. Another alternative is to use a scatter plot with points coloured by Z value...

Comment: Can you explain more on what has you confused and I will try a rewrite. The data as created is already like the output of greddata. The scatter plot isn't a great option as the data really do form little boxes of known size and scatters make that hard to replicate.

Comment: If the x direction is time, what is the "time dependent bins in the Y direction"? If the issue is speed of plotting and you have uniform gridded data then `imshow` is usually the fastest way to go (with extents specified from the limits of your data).

Comment: Y is time dependent energy measurement bins as the instrument changes mode. How would one use imshow as you can't tell it 1d 2d 2d extents either?